# Statistical test to assess significant difference in landcover selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, statistics, land-cover, wildlife-ecology

I have GPS collar data that I have used extract values to points through ArcGIS Pro on MODIS landcover data. From this I have a record on the number of times the animal has been in each landcover class. My data look like this:

| Landcover | Selection Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| Evergreen | 105 |
| WoodySavanna | 327 |
| Savanna | 30 |
| Grassland | 2 |
| Croplands | 2 |

It looks like there is a pattern of selection there so I am wondering what statistical test I can run to identify if there is a significant difference between the selection frequencies of the landcover classes?

Comment: You had a tag for R but make no mention in your question body as to how that’s relevant to your question so I removed it.

Comment: A chi-squared test? I'm no statistician you are better offer asking this question on [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you I've asked on there! I considered chi-square but wasn't sure as don't have expected & observed